# Understanding google's nutrition chart

Tags: nutrition, diet, micronutrients, macronutrient

When I googled "Chikpea", it shows following chart on right:

[image]

It says:

> *Per cent Daily Values are based on a 2,000 calorie diet. Your daily values may be higher or lower depending on your calorie needs.

Also it says "Amount Per 100 grand", "% Day Value*". Are three connected? What does it mean that "6g total fat for 100g chikpea for 9% of 2000 calorie diet"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The chart says that 100 grams of chickpeas have 364 calories, and 6 grams of total fat. It also tells you that the 6 grams of total fat is 9% of the "daily recommended value" for fat: this is because the total daily recommended value is 65 grams of fat, so 6/65 grams is about 9%.

These are fairly rough guidelines and there is no way for a universal rule to fit everyone. For a rough scaling you might base it on overall calorie needs, so if you only needed a 1200 calorie diet then the daily recommended fat would be about 65*1200/2000=39 grams, and 6 grams would be closer to 15% of the daily fat recommendation. There also may be more recent literature that suggests the guidelines should be updated, and I am not aware of any research that suggests these daily values should be met every day or that not meeting them exactly on average has any health impacts.

Comment: Helped me to interpret the chart very well. Thanks a ton!!!